# Symbol categories restrict attribute entry choices in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-collector, mobile-gis

I have a vector layer on ArcGIS Collector with a Field for recording the feature number or stating that the feature was 'Unsurveyable'. I want to symbolise these in Collector so I have one symbol of 'Unsurveyable' and one symbol for all other features. In ArcGIS I would simply use categories and have 'Unsurveyable' and 'All other values' as in the typical ArcGIS symbology tabs shown below.[image: ArcGIS desktop symbology] But if I symbolise it as shown in that screenshot, Collector only recognises 'Unsurveyable' features. The next screenshot shows what happens when I digitise a new feature and try to give it a number. Collector refuses to allow me to add anything but 'Unsurveyable' in the 'FieldID' attribute. On ArcGIS desktop the FieldID column can be a alpha-numeric code (typically F0199, F0200, F0201 etc) or 'Unsurveyable'.  [image: Collector interface] I would like to keep this symbology but still be able to add alpha-numeric FieldID numbers in Collector.

Comment: can you take a screenshot of your exact issue?

Comment: I have edited to include screenshots.

Comment: Based on this thread it seems to be impossible: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/169785